# Handling date strings with various length

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert dates with different formats to a unified format.
The data I get can be `MM/DD/YYYY` or `M/DD/YYYY` or `MM/D/YYYY` or `M/D/YYYY`.

As of now I can handle all except `M/D/YYYY`. 
Does anyone know how to solve that?

EDIT: Realized I didn't clarify which format I try to get, it's DD/MM/YYYY

My code as it is (not sure if it's the most efficient way):

```
var str = "2/13/2016"; // MM/DD/YYYY

var day = str.substr(3,2);
var month = str.substr(0,2);
var year = str.substr(6,4);

if(month.indexOf('/') > -1){
    month = month.replace('/','');
    var newM = '0' + month;
    day = str_date.substr(2,2);

    return day + '-' + newM + '-' + year;
}
else if(day.indexOf('/') > -1){
    day = day.replace('/','');
    var newD = '0' + day;
    year = str.substr(5,5);

    return newD + '-' + month + '-' + year;
}
else {
    return  day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use RegExp? IMO it'd be easier that way.

Comment: @Roomy Yes, but I don't know how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) with `en-GB` locale

```js
console.log(new Date("2/13/2016").toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
  year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' 
}))
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it gives me YYYY-MM-DD. Is there anyway to convert it to DD/MM/YYYY?

Comment: thank you! Now it works. Can't up vote your answer unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to split the input string by `/` into three substring parts, and then parse each part to a number via `Number.parseInt()`. The final step would be to format a result string based on the three parsed numbers.

In code that could look like this:

```js
var dateA = "2/13/2016"; // MM/DD/YYYY

function parseDate(str) {
  
  const parts = str.split('/').map(part => Number.parseInt(part));
  const [month, day, year] = parts;
  
  return `${day}-${month}-${year}`
  
}

/* M/D/YYYY case */
console.log(parseDate("2/3/2016"), "should equal 3-2-2016");
/* M/DD/YYYY case */
console.log(parseDate("2/03/2016"), "should equal 3-2-2016");
/* MM/D/YYYY case */
console.log(parseDate("02/3/2016"), "should equal 3-2-2016");
/* MM/DD/YYYY case */
console.log(parseDate("02/03/2016"), "should equal 3-2-2016");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) and it's ability to parse a date string in one of several possible formats and format the parsed date in to a specific format.

```js
const dates = ['1/8/2019', '01/8/2019', '1/08/2019', '01/08/2019'],
      dateFormats = ['M/D/YYYY', 'MM/D/YYYY', 'M/DD/YYYY', 'MM/DD/YYYY'];

const parsedDates = dates.map((s) => 
    moment(s, dateFormats).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
);

console.log(parsedDates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js" integrity="sha256-H9jAz//QLkDOy/nzE9G4aYijQtkLt9FvGmdUTwBk6gs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

look use this code

```
 const arr="2/13/2016".split('/').map(ele=>parseInt(ele))

 const [day,mounth,year]=arr;
```

then check the condition date is the less then 30 and mutch then or equal 1 for day
then check the condition date is the less then 12and mutch then or equal 1for munth
then check the condition date is the less then  `new Date().getFullYear()` mutch then or equal and more then 1950 then this correct date
then const `dateWant=`${day}/${mounth}/${year}`;`